# $f = (f_1,\cdots,f_n) : U\to \mathbb{R}^n$ has surjective $f'$ $\iff$ the vectors $\nabla f_1, \cdots, \nabla f_n$ are linearly independent.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra

I need to prove that:

$f = (f_1,\cdots,f_n) : U\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a submersion (its derivative is surjective for every $x$) $\iff$ the vectors $\nabla f_1, \cdots, \nabla f_n$ are linearly independent.

Here' s what I did:

If the derivative is surjective, it means that its image is the entire $\mathbb{R}^n$, therefore its dimension is $n$ and so the vectors, which form the jacobian matrix of $f'$ are linearly independent (dimension $n$ and $n$ columns implies that these $n$ columns are l.i.). Am I right? How do I return now? If the $n$ columns are linearly independent and there are $n$ of them, it means that the matrix has dimension $n$, right? So it means that $f'$ has dimension $n$... but why $f$ must be surjective then? How is surjectivity connected to dimension?

Comment: As a tip: you can use \nabla to make $\nabla$

Comment: @Guerlando: To start, a _vector space_ has a dimension (while a linear transformation and a matrix do not). Now, a linear transformation is surjective if and only if the dimension of its image is the dimension of the target space. A set $S$ of $n$ vectors in an $n$-dimensional space $V$ spans $V$ if and only if $S$ is linearly independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\Rightarrow)$ Indeed, if $f'$ is surjective, then $\operatorname{im}(f')=\Bbb R^n$, and hence the column vectors of the matrix of $f'$ span $\Bbb R^n$. Since there are $n$ of these column vectors, they form a basis for $\Bbb R^n$ and are thus linearly independent. Hence, $\nabla f_1,\cdots,\nabla f_n$ are linearly independent.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Now, suppose $\nabla f_1,\cdots,\nabla f_n$ are linearly independent, then the matrix formed by these column vectors is invertible. Hence, the associated operator is bijective, and therefore surjective. That is, $f'$ is surjective.